# iPhone-Cocos2d-Box2d game #include <list> problem

Tags: iphone, c++, c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a Cocos 2D game under development which also implements Box 2d and integration required me to change my .m classes to .mm

Now I am trying to use a code that draws Fruit Ninja style swiping effect using the code at https://github.com/hiepnd/CCBlade

When Compiling I get error at the line #include < list >

(CCBlade.h:14:0 CCBlade.h:14:15: error: list: No such file or directory)

It works fine when integrated with a .m file, but the error is when trying to use it with .mm

Any solutions for this ?

Comment: you forgot to detail the error

Comment: the error is in #include < list >  that states the compiler cant find a thing as "list"

Comment: (CCBlade.h:14:0 CCBlade.h:14:15: error: list: No such file or directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(after reading description in the comments)

the problem is likely that some translation that is *not* c++ or objc++ is including `<list>` via inclusion of `CCBlade.h`

check your build transcript for the failed file: `-x objective-c` here, the flag `-x` specifies the language. if it is not c++ or objc++, you'll get the error you presented.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file type within Xcode to "C++ header".

In Xcode 4:

- Select the CCBlade.h header file in the Project navigator.
- Reveal the File Inspector utility.
- Use the "File Type" popup in the "Identity and Type" section to change the file's type from "Default - C header" to "C++ header".
- Double-check that your Objc-C++ files are also identified as Obj-C++ files.